# Numerical AND Author-year modes for cites in the same file

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I want to use two ways to cite references in the same file. One numerical, and another one in the author-year style. I also want that only the numerical references appear at the end of the document in the "References", and the author-year references do not appear.

Example:

> This cite will be in the references [1], but not this other one [Doe14].
>
> **References**
>
> [1] Nice Author, "Nice article", 2000

As a variant, I may want to write the author-year references in the middle of the text:

> This cite will be in the references [1], and this one within the text of the document [Doe14].
>
> - [Doe14] Jon Doe, "Messing up with bibtex", 2014
>
> More text in the document here before the numeric bibliography.
>
> **References**
>
> [1] Nice Author, "Nice article", 2000

Comment: How is the reader supposed to know which bib entry belongs to [DOE14] if only numbers are in the bibliography? Maybe you are just looking for something like `\textcite{bibKey}` from the biblatex package?

Comment: I am preparing an application file for a job, and my articles are already in my CV, so I want to cite them just as [DC-xx], and to put only other authors' articles in the references. The second variant will be to use bibtex somehow to write my articles in the CV section, but I can do this by hand.
I will take a look at that package. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is a good idea; having two different styles for citations might be confusing and it is not a good practice. However, seeing the comments to the question, it seems to be required, so below there's a solution:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{aabcde.bib}
@BOOK{Carey,
   AUTHOR="G. V. Carey",
   TITLE="Mind the Stop: A Brief Guide to Punctuation",
   PUBLISHER="Penguin", YEAR="1958"}

@BOOK{Cooper,
   AUTHOR="Bruce M. Cooper",
   TITLE="Writing Technical Reports",
   PUBLISHER="Penguin", YEAR="1964"}

@BOOK{Gowers,
   AUTHOR="Sir Ernest Gowers",
   TITLE="The Complete Plain Words",
   PUBLISHER="Penguin", YEAR="1954"}
   (but first published by HMSO)

@BOOK{Hart,
   AUTHOR="Horace Hart",
   TITLE="[Hart's] Rules for Compositors and Readers 
          [at the Oxford University Press]",
   PUBLISHER="Oxford University Press",
   EDITION="39", YEAR="1983"}
   (but first published in 1893)
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multibib}

\newcites{auyear}{Secondary Literature}
\newsavebox\mybox

\begin{document}
\cite{Gowers}, \citeauyear{Carey}, \cite{Hart}, \citeauyear{Cooper}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{aabcde}

\bibliographystyleauyear{alpha}
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{\bibliographyauyear{aabcde}}
\end{lrbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is to use the [`multibib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multibib) package to define a secondary bibliography (the one with author-year labels that will not be printed). This secondary bibliography is defined with

```
\newcites{auyear}{Secondary Literature}
```

and will have `alph` style. You produce the citations for items in this bibliography using `\citeauyear{<key>}`.

The actual secondary bibliography is never printed since it's stored in a box that is never used.

If your document is called `mydoc.tex`, you process the document using

```
pdflatex mydoc
bibtex mydoc
bibtex auyear
pdflatex mydoc
pdflatex mydoc
```