# How to reference misc entries by number and article by author-year?

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, citing

I am working on a project and I use several types of reference.

I would like my `misc` entries to be referenced by number and my `article` entries by author-year pair in the same document.

Do you have a solution for me?

Comment: If you're still wondering about this, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299064/biblatex-two-bibliographies-with-different-styles-and-sortings and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156673/numerical-and-author-year-modes-for-cites-in-the-same-file?rq=1